# Don't field separate when a field separator is found inside of quotes

Tags: shell, awk, sed, ls

I have the output of this command `ls -lhp --group-directories-first`:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 aName aName 4.0K Jan 11 18:46  Desktop/
drwxr-xr-x 3 aName aName 4.0K Jan 13 16:43  Documents/
drwxr-xr-x 2 aName aName 4.0K Jan 12 18:47  Downloads/
drwxr-xr-x 2 aName aName 4.0K Jan 11 16:08  Music/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 aName aName 4.6M Jan 14 11:28 '2021-01-14 11-28-39.mov'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 aName aName 2.2M Jan 14 11:55 '2021-01-14 11-55-20.mkv'
```

I want to have only this:

```
Desktop/ 4.0K
Documents/ 4.0K
Downloads/ 4.0K
Music/ 4.0K
'2021-01-14 11-28-39.mov' 4.6M
'2021-01-14 11-55-20.mkv' 2.2M
```

So I can `awk` for just columns 9 and 5:

```
ls -lhp --group-directories-first | awk -F' ' '{print $9 " " $5}'
```

But when the file name contains a space, it field separates and everything after the space is missing.

Thanks for your wisdom and time!

Comment: Consider `du -sh *`

Comment: wow. neat! Except that this won't let me see directories from files, and is potentially a lot slower than ls

Comment: Alternatively, `awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[^[:space:]'"'"']+|'"'"'[^'"'"']+'"'"'"} {print $9" "$5}'`

Comment: That's crazy @WiktorStribiżew, mind to make a response explaining how it works, and i'll give you the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the right options:

```
ls -1shp --group-directories-first
```

`-s` to list sizes and `-1`, one entry per line.

If you require the size count to be after the file name, pipe it to `awk '{$(NF+1)=$1; $1=""}1`.

Comment: Nice, I have to `sed` it to remove the `Total` line: `ls -1shp --group-directories-first | sed 1d | awk '{$(NF+1)=$1; $1=""}1'` is it better to remove that line inside the same awk invocation?

Comment: @aName Not better, just more elegant IMO: `awk '{$(NF+1)=$1;$1=""}NR>1'`.

Comment: I'm trying to use this in `whiptail`, but whiptail also treats every space as a field thus I need to somehow feed it a file name and size as independed fields

Comment: @aName That seems to be a different question. I, for one, do not know how Whiptail works such that I could compose an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use find and printf:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -printf "'%f' %k\n"
```

Print the file name %f surrounded by single quotes as well as the 1k block size of the files/directories (%k)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the right delimiter, and with GNU awk, you may use `FPAT` to correctly delimit the whitespace separated fields that may be wrapped with single quotes:

```sh
ls -lhp --group-directories-first | \
  awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[^[:space:]'"'"']+|'"'"'[^'"'"']+'"'"'"} {print $9" "$5}'
```

The quotes look messy, but this is just how string concatenation works, you just put `'...'` or `"..."` beside one another, and the pattern is in fact `[^[:space:]']+|'[^']+'` and it matches

- `[^[:space:]']+` - one or more chars other than whitespace and `'`
- `|` - or
- `'[^']+'` - `'`, one or more chars other than `'` and then a `'` char.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/LNYCFO):

```sh
s="drwxrwxr-x 2 aName aName 4.0K Jan 11 18:46  Desktop/
drwxr-xr-x 3 aName aName 4.0K Jan 13 16:43  Documents/
drwxr-xr-x 2 aName aName 4.0K Jan 12 18:47  Downloads/
drwxr-xr-x 2 aName aName 4.0K Jan 11 16:08  Music/
w-rw-r--> -rw-rw-r-- 1 aName aName 4.6M Jan 14 11:28 '2021-01-14 11-28-39.mov'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 aName aName 2.2M Jan 14 11:55 '2021-01-14 11-55-20.mkv'"
 awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[^[:space:]'"'"']+|'"'"'[^'"'"']+'"'"'"} {print $9" "$5}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
Desktop/ 4.0K
Documents/ 4.0K
Downloads/ 4.0K
Music/ 4.0K
11:28 aName
'2021-01-14 11-55-20.mkv' 2.2M
```

Comment: I don't know why, but in my terminal `ls -lhp | awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[^[:space:]'"'"']+|'"'"'[^'"'"']+'"'"'"} {print $9" "$5}'
` still outputs something like this `2021-01-14 4.6M` (note the file name has been cut off after the space)

Comment: @aName Sorry, maybe you do not have a GNU awk.

Comment: @aName Or, your string is different from what you showed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `awk`

```
 ls -lhp --group-directories-first | awk -F' ' 'NR <= 4 {print $9, $5} NR > 4 {print $9,$10, $5}'

result:

Desktop/ 4.0K
Documents/ 4.0K
Downloads/ 4.0K
Music/ 4.0K
'2021-01-14 11-28-39.mov' 4.6M
'2021-01-14 11-55-20.mkv' 2.2M
```